# spring-boot property exception while externalizing datasource properties and using actuator

Tags: grails-orm, spring-boot

Im creating a small application using spring-boot + gorm + sqlserver datasource (very similar to Tim Yates' https://github.com/timyates/data-gorm-mysql/).

My datasource properties are in application.properties:

```
dbDriverClassName=...
dbUsername=...
```

My build.gradle has

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.0.0.RC1")
```

It works fine. But when I add the actuator to build.gradle, I get errors:

`compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")`

UPDATE (full stacktrace)

```
thread "main"                                                                                                                                                                              org.springfra
mework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentEndpoint': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
Invalid property 'dbUsername' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EnvironmentEndpoint]: Bean property 'dbUsername' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:278)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)




                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
2014-04-05 08:40:09.661  INFO 8136 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context..AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:619)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:880)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at gov.texas.iph.IphApplication.main(IphApplication.groovy:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dbUsername' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EnvironmentEndpoint]: Bean property 'dbUsername' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:922)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:728)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:624)
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:84)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:609)
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfiguratory.java:275)
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:225)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:318)
        ... 21 more
:bootRun FAILED
```

What am I missing? 
Thanks!

Comment: The [Getting Started Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gorm/) works for me (when I add the actuator). Maybe you should base your code on that instead? The link you provide is fine, but I see no reason to use a custom `DataSource` (not that it explains the error). We'd need to see more code or at least a stack trace to get closer to diagnosing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I changed the build.gradle line from RC1 to RC2 and there is no error now (tested switching back to RC1 to confirm error, and back to RC2 - no error).

```
compile("org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.0.0.RC2")
```

@Dave, thanks for the tip. But why do you say there is no reason to use custom DataSource, is there a better way?

I should have looked at repo.spring.io for latest version, but the stacktrace made me think it was an issue with actuator environment.

Comment: 1.0.0.RELEASE is available now. You should use that. And read the reference docs on `DataSource` configuration, maybe (or just delete your `@Bean` and let Spring take control?

Comment: @DaveSyer if i try gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.0.0.RELEASE, i get cannot download file error. 1.0.0.RC2 is the latest i could find in the spring repo artifactory.

btw, i was able to remove the Bean DataSource from code, use the spring.datasource.* properties. I had to include the starter-jdbc to build.gradle. I was assuming that starter-jdbc is not required if I use gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot.

Comment: So it's all working now? Sorry, I misread the RC2 thing (I thought you were using an old version of Spring Boot). Spring JDBC is needed to set up a database, so it's best to include it IMO.

Comment: @DaveSyer, yes its all working now. thx again for the help.

Just to clear up any confusion (for others who seek answer): the solution uses 1.0.0.RELEASE for everything except the gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot which is 1.0.0.RC2.